# Logging to browser console from within perl script

Tags: perl, console.log

I have an Angular2 application that has Perl running the back end scripts.

The Perl is sending back an error, and I finally nailed it down to the fact that a "read_ini()" function is failing, so it sends back a simple "Failed to read ini" and it's done. The read_ini() function, as you can probably deduce, locates and gets certain information from a .ini file. Thing is, it's a long function. I'm trying to nail down where in the function it's dying. It would be very useful to be able to print out to the browser JS console to help with this. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you not read the web server error logs - that's where backend output would end up normally

Comment: If your Perl is using CGI or FastCGI at the server side, you may want to use [CGI::Carp](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI/Carp.html) to send the errors to the browser. Remember to remove it when you are done.

Comment: I didn't set this system up and I can't seem to find where the error logs are.

Comment: /var/log/nginx/ or /var/log/httpd/ would be sensible places to check first if you are running Linux (and have a nginx or apache webserver)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer elsewhere.

At the top of the file I have 
`open my $savedSTDERR, ">&STDOUT";`

then, every `print` statement just logs to the JS console.

Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In your perl script:

```
use diagnostics;
use Carp qw(longmess);

eval {
    read_ini();
};
if ($@) {
     my $long_message = longmess( "error: '$@'");# stack trace about perl error 
     # send this $long_message as the http response to angular call.     
}
```

in angular controller code:

```
$http.get("perlscript.pl")
.then(function(response) {
       console.log(response.data); # stack trace about perl error should be shown in console log now.
},
function(response) {
      #handle error
});
```

Please try this. Just thrown you some code snippet as I don't know your code.